# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type number

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer, string-conversion

**I'm trying to solve one problem in HackerEarth. And I'm using javascript. Below is my code.**

```
// Sample code to perform I/O:

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                               // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});



// Warning: Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data to output will cause the test cases to fail


// Write your code here
function main(input) {
var data = input.split('\n');
var a = parseInt(data[0]);
var b = parseInt(data[1]);

var sum = a + b;
process.stdout.write(sum);


}
```

**And whenever I'm compiling this I'm getting the below error**

```
Execution failed.

Stack Trace:
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type number
at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:258:10)
at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:292:21)
at main (/hackerearth/JAVASCRIPT_NODE_3789_1f3d_d89e_d4f9/s_d3fb_2843_f025_60ef.njs:28:16)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/hackerearth/JAVASCRIPT_NODE_3789_1f3d_d89e_d4f9/s_d3fb_2843_f025_60ef.njs:13:4)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:194:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:261:12)
at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:292:21)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**Whenever I'm trying to convert the input string to integer I'm getting the above error. I simply couldn't do any arithmetic operations with the input data.
If any suggestions, please let me know...**

Comment: Convert sum to string instance and then write it

Comment: `process.stdout` is a Stream which has limits on what you can send into to it. Convert to string as @AlokRaj suggests. See [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) & [writeable.write](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be asked with reference to HackerEarth's basic I/O tutorial: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/tutorial/

Remember that `input` contains the entire string - not something like a "line by line" input like you'd get with C's `scanf()`.

You split the input on the basis of the newline. That's fine. But then you just converted them to `int`s and joined them and tried to print them.
The problem with that is that "helloworld" is not an integer. If you try to parse it as one, it'll give out `NaN`. Adding that to the first `10` will also get `NaN` and you will have a problem.

Instead, do something like this:

```
function main(input) {
    let inputParts = input.split('\n');
    let num = parseInt(inputParts[0]);
    inputParts[0] = (num * 2).toString(); // inputParts is now ["10", "helloworld"]
    process.stdout.write(inputParts.join('\n'));
}
```

We just parse the part that is supposed to be parsed, and convert the output back to string before printing it out.

Note: the `.toString()` on line 3 is optional - since when we do concatenation of a number and a string, the output is a string. I converted it to a string just to be safe, but it's up to you if you want to do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried   process.stdout.write(""+sum);     and it worked for me.

Comment: You should expand this answer to indicate why it works.